# Parse json field that may be an JSONObject or JSONArray in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, arrays

I'm using the json.org library to parse my json. But I have a field called "messages" that depending on the number of messages may come as a null field, a JSONObject (if there is only one message) or a JSONArray if there are multiple messages. I'm having some trouble to treat this because I have to read it using the correct object type as it will return an error if i don't make it right. Oh, and it's java.

Can anyone help me? I'm sure there is a "standart" way to treat this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [JSONTokener](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html):

```
JSONTokener jk = ...; // whatever you're currently doing.

// Probably a loop here around the below...

Object o = jk.nextValue();
if(o instanceof JSONObject){
  JSONObject jo = (JSONObject)o;
  // Do something with jo.
}else if(o instanceof JSONArray){
  JSONArray ja = (JSONArray)o;
  // Do something with ja.
}else{
  // Is null or another type.  (Maybe do something?)
}
```

See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue%28%29 for all the other types that can be returned from `nextValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a simple utility method like so:

```
private void processMessages(Object messages) {
    JSONArray jsonArr;
    if (messages instanceof JSONObject) {
        jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        jsonArr.put(messages);
    } else if (messages instanceof JSONArray) {
        jsonArr = messages;
    }

    // Process all the JSONObjects in the same way
    for (final JSONObject obj : jsonArr) {

    }
}
```

And then from within your code:

```
if (jsonObj.has("messages")) {
    processMessages(jsonObj.get("messages"));
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Really liked it!